# Blank rows when connecting Survey Monkey with Power BI

Tags: powerbi, surveymonkey

I have 271 survey responses collected in Survey Monkey and am trying to pull that data in to Power BI. When I do this, 119 of the responses get errors and show up as entirely blank rows in the data source in Power BI. The error message for these rows are all the same and it looks like this: 
[image]

I have tried looking up this error, and it seems that this happens when there are duplicated fields or data, but I don't have a field titled '278832033'. I have also checked the responses in Survey Monkey, but all 271 of them appear normally and are not duplicated responses. I also checked to see if the 119 error rows are incomplete responses, but that doesn't seem to be the case as there are incomplete responses that show up fine in Power BI without errors.

Does anyone have any ideas for what more I could look into?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your image link but got: "502 Bad Gateway cloudflare"

Just wondering, how do you connect Power BI to Surveymonkey? Can it handle all the oAuth authentication and paging responses and JSON parsing?

Comment: I followed these steps - https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Microsoft-Power-BI-Integration . It seems to handle the authorization. I just can't seem to figure out why nearly half of the rows are being imported with every row as a error.

Comment: Thanks Kira. Unfortunately for us "This integration is only available to SurveyMonkey Enterprise users. ". so I can't test it.